# unit-тесты для класса, реализующего следующий интерфейс

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, юнит-тесты

Как написать юнит-тесты для класса, реализующего следующий интерфейс :

```
public interface IDatabase  
{  
void CreateEntityTables(IEnumerable<string> tables);   
IEntity SelectById(string table, Guid id);  
void Delete(string table, Guid id, bool inTransaction);  
void Save(IEntity obj, bool inTransaction);  
void CommitTransaction();  
void RollbackTransaction();  
}  

public interface IEntity  
{  
Guid Id { get; set; }  
string Tablename { get; }  
}
```

Comment: Создайте таблицу, сохраните сущность, получите сущность, удалите сущность, проверьте что сущность больше нельзя получить. В чём ваш вопрос?

Comment: @Monk
 
как выглядит метод создания таблицы и юнит тест для этого метода, не могли бы показать?

Comment: Так вам его и надо написать, тесты тут не при чём. Как именно создавать - дело целиком ваше, гугл подскажет. Ну или задавайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь@monk

Comment: Что значит тесты не причём,   зачем вы вообще отвечаете вопросами на вопрос, сначала перевели с английского названия методов, потом в гугл отправили, не знаете , зачем тогда отвечать? @monk

Comment: вам нужно для тестов подсунуть тестовую базу, и после вызова каждого метода проверять что нужный эффект достигнут, как то так, если конечно я вас понял правильно. Сложность в том, что перед вызовом метода тест должен инициализировать базу в нужном состоянии, а вот как это правильно сделать зависит от БД которую вы используете.

Comment: @Timon вы говорите, что вам нужно написать тесты на класс, который реализует интерфейс. Сам класс то у вас есть или его тоже надо написать?

Comment: @rdorn
а если нету привязки к БД, то есть, дан вот интерфейс только и задание? вроде бы через moq можно, но я не могу даже простейший тест для запроса написать, т к не могу тупо найти материалы, где это описывается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окей, раз вы не видите проблем в вопросе.

Создаем классы, реализующие интерфейс:

```
  public class Database : IDatabase
  {
    public void CreateEntityTables(IEnumerable<string> tables)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEntity SelectById(string table, Guid id)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Delete(string table, Guid id, bool inTransaction)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Save(IEntity obj, bool inTransaction)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void CommitTransaction()
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void RollbackTransaction()
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }

  public class Entity : IEntity
  {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Tablename { get; }
  }
```

Этого достаточно, чтобы начать. Пишем тест на создание таблиц:

```
  [TestClass]
  public class DatabaseCRUD
  {
    [TestMethod]
    public void CreateTable()
    {
      IDatabase database = new Database();
      database.CreateEntityTables(null);
    }
  }
```

Интерфейс не дает никакого способа проверить, что таблицы созданы, а значит - достаточно чтобы не падало. В текущем виде падает, но это тоже результат работы теста. Тест написан, задание выполнено.

Ещё пара примеров, на всякий случай:

Сохранение и получение сущности обратно. В текущем виде падает, значит тест работает.

```
[TestMethod]
public void SaveEntity()
{
  IDatabase database = new Database();
  IEntity entity = new Entity();
  database.Save(entity, false);
  var entityFromDatabase = database.SelectById(entity.Tablename, entity.Id);
  Assert.AreEqual(entity, entityFromDatabase);
}
```

Как продолжение - транзакционное сохранение. Т.е. до коммита из базы забирать в принципе нечего. Я бы ожидал примерно такого поведения:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SaveEntityInTransaction()
{
  IDatabase database = new Database();
  IEntity entity = new Entity();
  database.Save(entity, true);
  var entityFromDatabase = database.SelectById(entity.Tablename, entity.Id);
  Assert.IsNull(entityFromDatabase);
  database.CommitTransaction();
  entityFromDatabase = database.SelectById(entity.Tablename, entity.Id);
  Assert.AreEqual(entity, entityFromDatabase);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ и пояснения, буду от этого отталкиваться и разбираться. А как в данном случае выглядел бы запрос на создание БД с помощью MOQ, если не сложно, не могли бы пояснить этот момент?

Comment: @Timon моки могут быть любыми, но они всё равно не дают вам сделать нормальный запрос. Нужен запрос - делайте реальный запрос в реальную базу.

Comment: но это ведь будет уже интеграционное тестирование, а тут задание на модульное, или я что-то не так понимаю?

Comment: @Timon а это к вам вопросы, а не ко мне. Про модульное\интеграционное тестирование у вас в вопросе не написано. Более того, а как ещё можно тестировать интерфейс создания табличек в базе, кроме как создавая таблички в базе? Остальное по моему бессмысленно совсем.

Comment: работая с фейковой бд, например? нужно же протестировать запросы, а не базу данных

Comment: @Timon можно попробовать конкретно под этот кейс подогнать - просто хранить где то список названий табличек, которые надо было создать. Этот список собсна и будет вашей БД. В любом случае, я считаю это изобретением велосипеда.